# Function overloading in Fortran 2008

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, overloading, fortran2008

I'm beginning with Fortran 2008 and I'm struggling with OOP greatly. It seems, that there are very few materials, which explain a very basic OOP concepts in 2008 language standard.

I've found information about inheritance, but I was unable to find any info about polymorphism.

So if I wanted to overload a function in C++, I can do it like this (example from Wikipedia):

```
// volume of a cube
int volume(const int s)
{
    return s*s*s;
}

// volume of a cylinder
double volume(const double r, const int h)
{
    return 3.1415926*r*r*static_cast<double>(h);
}

// volume of a cuboid
long volume(const long l, const int b, const int h)
{
    return l*b*h;
}
```

But, how am I supposed to do the same thing in Fortran 2008?

Comment: I don't have time right now to answer this but if you go to the Portland Group website and root around you'll find some articles written a few years back which provide perhaps the best introductory material to the topic of Fortran OOP that is available without cost.

Comment: Your examples aren't really "OOP" as such, but the concepts of _generics_ (from Fortran 90 onward) would be suitable.  There may be a good set of questions here addressing their basic use, but you'll certainly find many which have them at heart.

Comment: Further, you mention "polymorphism" but there's nothing relating to (Fortran's concept of) polymorphism in your examples.  Are you asking about how to do the same thing as the C++ example in Fortran, or about resolving procedures where there is polymorphism? [These are two related things, but different enough that covering both would likely be far too broad as a single question.]

Comment: @francescalus Ok, I'm sorry for the confusion. I'm asking, how can I overload functions to have the same identifier, but different parameters. And I mentioned OOP, as I intend to use it mainly for method overloading.

Comment: These sre just Fortran 90 generics. You will find plenty of information about them here.

Comment: Here are the links alluded to by @HighPerformanceMark: [Code Reusability](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n1a3.htm), 
[Data Polymorphism](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v3n2a2.htm) (perhaps most related to your particular question), [Parameterized Derived Types](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v5n2a4.htm) and [User-Defined Derived Type Input/Output](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v6n2a3.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of overloading as given in the C++ examples has an implementation in Fortran, dating back to the *generics* of Fortran 90.

Given a set of *specific* procedures a generic identifier may be used to identify this set.  In this answer I'll give a very high-level introduction to this concept.  There are a lot of subtleties which may require further reading/questions to address.

Unlike the C++ example, our Fortran specific procedures need to be named separately.  Let's have the two functions (third can be added *mutatis mutandis*)

```
integer function volume_cube(s)
  integer, intent(in) :: s
  ...
end function volume_cube

double precision function volume_cylinder(r, h)
  double precision, intent(in) :: r
  integer, intent(in) :: h
  ...
end function volume_cylinder
```

We can then add a generic interface for something called `volume`:

```
interface volume
  procedure volume_cube, volume_cylinder
end interface
```

We can then reference the generic `volume` and the compiler will determine which specific function to use.

There is much more to learn about generics, including what else they offer beyond this simple overloading.  One should also understand how specific procedures are resolved (simple in this case, not so in others) and the restrictions on which specific procedures may be lumped together.  As you use generics problematic cases are likely to have particular questions.  I answer here only as I couldn't see an introductory question and I don't attempt to address the many varied difficulties or values.

---

Complete example

```
module mod

  private

  interface volume
     module procedure volume_cube, volume_cylinder
  end interface volume
  public volume

contains
  integer function volume_cube(s)
    integer, intent(in) :: s
    volume_cube = s**3
  end function volume_cube

  double precision function volume_cylinder(r, h)
    double precision, intent(in) :: r
    integer, intent(in) :: h
    volume_cylinder = 3.1415926d0*r**2*h
  end function volume_cylinder

end module mod

  use mod

  print*, volume(2), volume(2d0,4)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you mind to mention a possible usage of these generics in the class? I mean specifically method overloading.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the class"?  I think you mean (you can look up the terminology to check) for generic type-bound procedures.  Unfortunately, in those cases some of the big complications come into play.  If you mean that, I'd suggest reading up on type-bound procedures first and then if necessary asking a new specific question.  (I don't think I can keep this answer concise when also including that stuff - but that stuff is interesting.)

Answer (score 1):

expanding Fancescalus example:

```
module Pablo_Dali
private

interface volume_Cube
  module procedure volume_cube_Int, volume_cube_Float, Colume_cube_Double
!add in 8, 16, and 64 bit ints... and complex??
end interface volume
public volume_Cube

contains
  integer function volume_cube_Int(s)
    integer, intent(in) :: s
    volume_cube_Int = s**3
  end function volume_cube_int

  float function volume_cube_Float(s)
    float, intent(in) :: s
    volume_cube_float = s**3
  end function volume_cube_Float

  integer function volume_cube_Double(s)
    DOUBLE, intent(in) :: s
    volume_cube_Double = s**3
  end function volume_cube_Double
end module Pablo_Dali
```

then the code:

```
PROGRAM Cube_Volume
USE Pablo_Dali
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: I_Side, I_Volume
FLOAT   :: F_Side, F_Volume
DOUBLE  :: D_Side, D_Volume

I_Side = 1
F_Side = 1.0E0
D_Side = 1.0D0

WRITE(*,*)'[INT]    ',I_Side,' cubed=', volume_cube(I_Side)
WRITE(*,*)'[FLOAT]  ',F_Side,' cubed=', volume_cube(F_Side)
WRITE(*,*)'[DOUBLE] ',D_Side,' cubed=', volume_cube(D_Side)

END PROGRAM Cube_Volume
```